# Connect a U.FL connector to a printed PCB antenna

Tags: rf, surface-mount, pcb-antenna

I want to connect a U.FL connector to a PCB antenna on the ATWINC15x0-MR210PB, which is a meandered inverted F Antenna (IFA). I am not sure where to begin termination. C21 is where the antenna signal starts.

[image: Schematic]

[image: PCB antenna]